# How to add Search?

Tags: android, search

How do I add search functionality in my android app? I have a listview in which I want to add search functionality. I have the code but I don't know how do I integrate it properly with my app. Here is the code:

```
private ListView listView;
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
int dataSize;
String[]breed;
public Dog listDog = new Dog();
private SearchView searchView;
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
    initInstances();
    setupSearchView();
}

private void initInstances() {

    prepareData();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDog);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listViewClickListener);
}

private void setupSearchView() {
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Искать кота");
}

private void prepareData() {

    int resId[] = {R.drawable.german_shepherd, R.drawable.labrador_retriever, R.drawable.blue_dog, R.drawable.beagle
            , R.drawable.boxer, R.drawable.golden_retriever, R.drawable.poodle, R.drawable.pug, R.drawable.siberian_husky,
            R.drawable.great_dane, R.drawable.german_shepherd, R.drawable.labrador_retriever, R.drawable.blue_dog, R.drawable.beagle
            , R.drawable.boxer, R.drawable.golden_retriever, R.drawable.poodle, R.drawable.pug, R.drawable.siberian_husky,
            R.drawable.great_dane, R.drawable.german_shepherd, R.drawable.labrador_retriever, R.drawable.blue_dog, R.drawable.beagle
            , R.drawable.boxer, R.drawable.golden_retriever, R.drawable.poodle, R.drawable.pug, R.drawable.siberian_husky,
            R.drawable.great_dane, R.drawable.german_shepherd, R.drawable.labrador_retriever, R.drawable.blue_dog, R.drawable.beagle
            , R.drawable.boxer, R.drawable.golden_retriever, R.drawable.poodle, R.drawable.pug, R.drawable.siberian_husky,
            R.drawable.great_dane};

    breed = new String [] {"German shepherd", "Labrador retriever", "Bull dog", "Beagle",
            "Boxer", "Golden retriever", "Poodle", "Pug", "Siberian husky",
            "Great dane", "German shepherd", "Labrador retriever", "Bull dog", "Beagle",
            "Boxer", "Golden retriever", "Poodle", "Pug", "Siberian husky",
            "Great dane", "German shepherd", "Labrador retriever", "Bull dog", "Beagle",
            "Boxer", "Golden retriever", "Poodle", "Pug", "Siberian husky",
            "Great dane", "German shepherd", "Labrador retriever", "Bull dog", "Beagle",
            "Boxer", "Golden retriever", "Poodle", "Pug", "Siberian husky",
            "Great dane"};


    String description[] = {getString(R.string.Юлмарт), getString(R.string.ЮлияСадовая), getString(R.string.Ювелирныймагазин585), getString(R.string.Альфа)
            , getString(R.string.Электромонтаж), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКарла93), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКарла363), getString(R.string.ДобрыеСемена), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКрасная93)
            , getString(R.string.Глобус), getString(R.string.ПланетаДетства), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКрасная152), getString(R.string.Золушка), getString(R.string.Офискласс118)
            , getString(R.string.СалонцветовLadyFlower), getString(R.string.ДекорЮг), getString(R.string.Глобус), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКрасная25), getString(R.string.ОфисКласс106)
            , getString(R.string.ПятёрочкаБувальцева26), getString(R.string.БаронДиваноффКрасная1), getString(R.string.Рынок), getString(R.string.Новинтех), getString(R.string.ГлорияДжинс)
            , getString(R.string.ЦифровойсупермаркетDNS), getString(R.string.Евроремонт), getString(R.string.Гейзер), getString(R.string.Нива), getString(R.string.ДвериАдамКомунистическая20)
            , getString(R.string.ЦветыДоставка), getString(R.string.БытКубани), getString(R.string.РынокКореновскоеРАЙПО), getString(R.string.Золушка), getString(R.string.ДинскиеКолбасы)
            , getString(R.string.Цветы), getString(R.string.Тимур), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКомунистическая20), getString(R.string.АгрокомплексКарла363), getString(R.string.МебельныймагазинРз59)
            , getString(R.string.Изумруд),};
    dataSize = resId.length;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,breed);

    Log.d("khem", "dataSize " + resId.length);
    Log.d("khem", "breed " + resId.length);
    Log.d("khem", "description " + resId.length);



    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        Log.d("khem", " " + i);
        Dog dog = new Dog(resId[i], breed[i], description[i]);
        dogs.add(dog);
    }

    listDog.setDogs(dogs);

    //Log.d("khem",listDog);
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}


public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        listView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        listView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

/*************************
 * Listener
 ***************************/

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listViewClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "POSITION:= " + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("resId",listDog.getDogs().get(position).getResId());
        intent.putExtra("breed",listDog.getDogs().get(position).getBreed());
        intent.putExtra("desc",listDog.getDogs().get(position).getDescription());

        startActivity(intent);
    }

};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Change ListAdapter to SimpleAdapter

2- make the adapter global variable,

**then you can use getFilter method**

Note: I'm getting the word I want to search for in the array from editText, and perform search while writing the word using TextChanged listener

```
EditText grabResults;
grabResults.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

you can put where ever you want :)

```
adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
```